# Netbeans 7.4 or 8 won't create or open project when Cloning Git project

Tags: git, netbeans, github, netbeans-7

First time ever using Git, so I'm sure it's me and not Netbeans.  However, I'm following every instruction/tutorial to the letter, and I'm not able to get things to work...

I'm trying to clone a Git project and create a new Netbeans project from it.  According to all of the instructions & tutorials I've read, a 'Clone Finished' dialog window should be appearing which allows me to create a new project from the clone.  However, I get nothing.  I originally was using 7.4 and tried multiple times, to no avail.  All of the files are downloading and I'm not getting any errors.  The Git Repository Browser shows all of the correct data, but just nothing is happening after cloning.  And when I point Netbeans to the directory in which the repository was cloned, there's no project to open.  I thought it might be a Java/Netbeans 7.4 issue, so I uninstalled and reinstalled the latest version of Java JRE and Netbeans 8, and I am still having the EXACT same results.  Everything is there, but I can't create a new project.

If it's any help, here is the output log from the clone process:

```
==[IDE]== Apr 4, 2014 8:27:21 PM Validating destination...
==[IDE]== Apr 4, 2014 8:27:21 PM Validating destination... finished.
==[IDE]== Apr 4, 2014 8:27:21 PM Cloning...
git init C:\Projects\MyProject
git fetch https://github.com/MyProject/website.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
Branch  : origin/master
Old Id : null
New Id : 51hhcd539567553c1f85730gb8805f1e423b1593
Result : NEW

setting up remote: origin
git branch --track master origin/master
git checkout master
git reset --hard master
git submodule status
==[IDE]== Apr 4, 2014 8:29:57 PM Cloning... finished.
```

I'm not sure what else to do here, and I haven't found any solutions to this anywhere.  Has anyone else had this issue and know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the clone contain any project types NetBeans supports?

If not, create one via "New Project...|HTML5|HTML5 Application with Existing Sources" or use the PHP equivalent.

Comment: I can't believe that was it. Of course I tried everything except that, lol. So simple, thank you!